# Looking for improvement on double left join between two tables/queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010

I have a query which uses a double join, two left joins, from a table to an query. It works fine, but recently I've noticed some lag, as more records get added to the underlying tables. My concern is the lag and was wondering if there could be a better way to approach this.

I also did some research on nested queries, but my attempts didn't give me the desired output/results.

```
SELECT 
 BulkStockV1.TyreIndividualID, 
 BulkStockV1.TyrePatternID, 
 BulkStockV1.TyreStatusID, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.JobCardDate,
 qSelStockFitmentNew.JobCardNumber, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.Horse_ID, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.Trailer_ID, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.WheelPos, 
 BulkStockV1.BulkOrderID, 
FROM BulkStockV1 
LEFT JOIN qSelStockFitmentNew 
**ON (BulkStockV1.TyrePatternID = qSelStockFitmentNew.Pattern_ID) 
AND (BulkStockV1.TyreIndividualID = qSelStockFitmentNew.TyreIndividual_ID)**
ORDER BY 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.JobCardDate, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.JobCardNumber, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.Horse_ID, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.Trailer_ID, 
 qSelStockFitmentNew.WheelPos, 
 BulkStockV1.TyreIndividualID;
```

I've tried removing the second join and it speeds up the query, but the results/output change as well.

Comment: In the query you've provided, there is only 1 left join table. Where is the other table?

Comment: See my previous replies.   BulkStockV1 is a table, left joined onto another query, qSelstockFitmentNew.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DDL including indexes & for SQL performance it includes EXPLAIN output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what I did wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM BulkStockV1 bs LEFT JOIN
     qSelStockFitmentNew sfn
     ON bs.TyrePatternID = sfn.Pattern_ID AND
        bs.TyreIndividualID = sfn.TyreIndividual_ID
ORDER BY . . .
```

First, `BulkStockV1` is probably a view.  As least, that is how I would interpret the `V1`.  If so, then that could be the cause of your performance issue.

For this query, you want a single composite index on `qSelStockFitmentNew(Pattern_ID, TyreIndividual_ID)`.  Because this is a `LEFT JOIN`, the indexes are better on the second table.

You have an `ORDER BY`.  Alas, it is mixing columns from both tables, so there is no way that you can eliminate the sorting using an index.

Comment: I'm busy with some restructuring on my database, as new requirements were identified.  I've made a dupplicate of a existing table(Bulkstock) to be able to test some ideas without compromising the data. BulkStockv1 is this duplicate table and not a view.

Comment: Table BulkStockV1 is therefor left joined onto query a query, qSelStockFitmentNew.   As the Order By are only on the fields from the query, would it help if I do the sorting in the query, qSelFitmentNew, first?